# Find total number of groups formed

Tags: permutations, multisets

This is smaller problem of a bigger question.

Example:
if  $N= 3$,

then answer is $5$ as  groups would be $\{(1),(2),(3)\},\{(1),(2,3)\},\{(1,2),(3)\},\{(1,3),(2)\},\{(1,2,3)\}$

Problem I am facing $\to$ To make a generalized formula for this?

with $n=1$ it is $1$, i.e. $\{(1)\}$

with $n=2$ it is $2$ i.e. $\{(1),(2)\},\{(1,2)\}$, i.e. $2$ can either be clubbed with $1$ or taken separately in $\{(1)\}$

with $n=3$, it is $5$, i.e. $3$ can either be clubbed with $1$ or with $2$ or taken separately in its first grouping in $n=2$ taken separately or with $(1,2)$ in its second grouping

with $n=4$, it is $15$. I cannot make out generalized formula for this.

Comment: Are you sure the value for $N=4$ is 16 and not 15? I think what you're after are known as _set partitions_  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks. I manually counted it, made a mistake

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for the suggestion as well :)